# Is the fractional part additive?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Define the fractional part of a real number $x$ as $\{x\}=x - \lfloor x \rfloor$.
I would like to know whether it holds that for two real numbers $a$ and $b$ we have that $\{a+b\}=\{a\}+\{b\}$. I tried this on a few particular cases and it worked, but I don't know how one should go about proving it. I only observed that it is obviously true if one of the numbers is an integer.

Comment: Try $a=b=\frac 12$.  or $a=b=.9$

Comment: What if $\{a\}+\{b\} \ge 1$?

Comment: But it is true that $\{a\} + \{b\}= \{a+b\} + \begin{cases} 0\\1\end{cases}$ which should be easy to prove by definitions and examples.

Comment: Oooh!  Another way of putting it is that $\{\{a\}+ \{b\}\}=\{a +b\}$. In a way it's like remainders.  The remainder of $a+b$ isn't necessarily the remainder of $a$ plus the remainder of $b$ but it is the *remainder* of that sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{a+b\} = (a+b)-[a+b]$ and $\{a\} + \{b\} = (a-[a])+(b-[b]) = (a+b) -([a]+[b])$.

So $\{a+b\}=\{a\} + \{b\} \iff [a+b] =[a]+[b]$.

But $[a]\le a < [a]+1$ and $[b]\le b < [b]+1$ so

$[a]+[b] \le a+ b \le [a]+[b] + 2$

It's feasible that for some $a,b$ we could have $a+b > [a]+[b]+1$ in which case $[a+b] > [a]+[b]+1$ and $\{a+b\}\ne \{a\} + \{b\}$.

The will occur if the fractional parts add up to more than $1$

Consider $a= 1.51$ and $b=3.52$.  $\{a\}+\{b\} = 0.51 + 0.52= 1.03$ but $\{a+b\} =\{5.03\}= 0.03$.

======

But it is true that  $\{a\} + \{b\}= \{a+b\} + \begin{cases} 0\\1\end{cases}$.

Comment: I think a single counterexample would have sufficed; both (the first two) comments above are more than enough.  I find your answer far too verbose to be as helpful as the (first two) comments given above.

Comment: I wanted to show how if one *didn't* know the answer of the top of one's head one could figure it out.

Comment: Thank you! So we add $1$ if $\{a\} +\{b\} \ge 1$?

Comment: Exactly!  $\{X\}$ is *always* between $0$ and $1$ but it can be very close to $1$.  And so $\{X\} + \{Y\}$ is always between $0$ and $2$ but it can be very close to $2$ if both $\{X\}$ and $\{Y\}$ are close to $1$.  But we *can't* have $\{X+Y\}\ge 1$!  In the cases where $\{X\}$ and $\{Y\}$ are large enough to have the sum "go over a digit" then... well the sum goes over a digit.

Answer (score 1):

Let us use the representation of the number $a$ as

$$a=a'+a''$$ where $a$ is an integer and $0\le a'<1$. This decomposition is unique.

We can write

$$(a'+a'')+(b'+b'')=(a'+b')+(a''+b'')=(a'+b'+1)+(a''+b''-1).$$

As $0\le a''<1$ and $0\le b''<1$, we have $$0\le a''+b''<1\lor0\le a''+b''-1<1.$$

Hence

$$\{a+b\}=\{a\}+\{b\}\lor\{a+b\}=\{a\}+\{b\}-1.$$